# MacBook Pro 2019 13 inch random shut off

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, crash, kernel-panic

So I have a MacBook Pro 2019 13 inch, at the moment it doesn't have macOS on it. Trying to run Internet Recovery gives the prompt: "A software update is required to use this startup disk". Clicking on Update after that just shuts it down and makes it restart.

I have already tried several macOS images (High Sierra, Catalina, Monterey, Ventura) but all of them have the same problem (some do load in but again the device randomly shuts down installation). I think there is a problem with the drivers so that's why it shuts down (kernel panic?). I tried running Apple Diagnostics, but this takes me to Internet Recovery.

Is there some way to fix this? The battery is still good so it's not because of that (even if it was bad, that wouldn't explain the other problems)

If there is any info that's still needed to help me, just tell me.

I hope someone knows how to fix this.

Comment: Do you have a 2nd Mac? It's possible you may have to use Apple Configurator app to  fix the firmware. Otherwise, take it to an Apple Store.

Comment: @benwiggy Yes I do! How could I fix it? Thanks for the response!!

Comment: @benwiggy Although... I have a MacBook Pro 13 inch 2014.. with Big Sur... It won't detect it, if I install a patched monterey version, will it be able to detect it?